# InflateException in AppPreferences

Tags: java, android, kotlin, inflate-exception

App runs fine on Android 6.0 and 8.1 but when I'm trying to run it on Android 10 it crashes

The first thing that I see is: "Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor" but if it is a bug in library itself how can I fix it.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gtl.android.gteasyclock, PID: 6889
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gtl.android.gteasyclock/com.gtl.android.gtapp.core.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:409)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:426)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:437)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:490)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:502)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:334)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:271)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:343)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:670)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:629)
        at com.gtl.android.gtapp.settings.AppPreferences.<init>(AppPreferences.kt:124)
        at com.gtl.android.gtapp.core.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:192)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:392)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:426) 
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:437) 
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:490) 
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:502) 
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:334) 
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:271) 
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:343) 
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:670) 
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:629) 
        at com.gtl.android.gtapp.settings.AppPreferences.<init>(AppPreferences.kt:124) 
        at com.gtl.android.gtapp.core.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:192) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Text array resource ID #0x7f0e007f
        at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:660)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:1063)
        at android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference.onGetDefaultValue(MultiSelectListPreference.java:229)
        at android.preference.Preference.<init>(Preference.java:320)
        at android.preference.DialogPreference.<init>(DialogPreference.java:98)
        at android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference.<init>(MultiSelectListPreference.java:58)
        at android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference.<init>(MultiSelectListPreference.java:69)
        at android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference.<init>(MultiSelectListPreference.java:73)
```

This line

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.preferences, readAgain)
```

uses R.xml.preferences (preferences.xml):
https://pastebin.com/x0EWfFEE

Comment: It's probably an issue with one of your `MultiSelectListPreference`s referencing an invalid array resource.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you very much !!

Comment: This seems to cause the issue how to fix it ? ' android:defaultValue="@string/empty" '